# Table dropdown not found while categorisation in spotfire charts

Tags: spotfire

I am creating a chart in spotfire and I am using 2 tables for analysis. I have created relation between tables using column matched feature. I have assigned primary table to the chart and linked it the child table. Even then when going to select a column for categorisation from primary table, I am not able to find table dropdown while selecting field from second table for categorisation.

I have matched country id fields manually from both tables using column matched feature

[image]

Even then I am not able to find table dropdown to select field from country table

[image]